# Why does cURL always return a status code?

Tags: php, curl

I have some PHP code that calls into the cURL library.  I'm using it to get JSON data.

I have set cURL opt 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER' to 1, but still get status code..

Code follows:

```
<?php
function fetch_page($url)
{

    $ch = curl_init();

    $array = array(
        'include'=>'ayam'
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    return $result;
} 

$return  = fetch_page(MY_LINK_URL);

echo json_decode($return);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code looks totally correct. Try `var_dump($result)` before returning it to see what it is exactly.

Also, set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to 1 and check the view source of the output in your browser; both of these can help debug the issue. Edit the question and post the results if so we can help more effectively.

**Update:** Since you are using HTTPS, also add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: @pensilhijau: Have a look at the update, maybe that will help?

Answer (score 4):

That looks correct.  I actually have the same problem, but when I added

```
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

it returns json code correctly instead of returning 1(True).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php),

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on
>   failure. However, if the
>   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set,
>   it will return the result on success,
>   FALSE on failure.

So that means you should get
success: the result
failure: FALSE (which is echoed as 0)

Also, if you are fetching JSON, and need to access it, use **json_decode()** not json_encode().

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should tell us wich url you're pointing (and wich version of php you are running). 
I've tried with php 5.3 on "www.google.com" and it worked as expected ($result contains the whole webpage)

Comment: the url that i pointing is use https, is problem with that?  and im use php 5.1

Comment: No, it should be no problem...are you completly sure the page you are pointing is OK?

Answer (score 0):

Might of had a similar problem: 
 - [cURL on local dev network problem with virtual host naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437177/curl-on-local-dev-network-problem-with-virtual-host-naming)

Before you close your curl handle output this:

```
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
curl_close ($ch);
```

Here was my solution for getting around the virtual host

```
// This is your Virtual Hosts name
$request_host   = 'dev.project'; 

// This is the IP
$request_url    = '192.168.0.1';

$headers = array("Host: ".$request_host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url.'?'.$request_args);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a number of reasons why `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` can be ignored, and SSL certificate checking is only one of them:

In my case the culprit was `CURLOPT_POST` which I had set to `true`. I was expecting to get back a string consisting of the HTTP response header plus the response itself. Instead I was getting status code `1`. Go figure. Thankfully I did not need the HTTP header so the solution for me was:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

If I did need the header info, I don't know what I would do. I've wasted an insane amount of time tracking down the problem.

Damn you PHP curl! (waves fist in anger)