# Using guzzle to send post request to laravel based apps

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, guzzle

I'am having 2 laravel apps in my localhost (for testing purpose)... and I want my first laravel apps send POST data to my second laravel apps and then save those data to mysql database.

So here is my first laravel apps route

```php
Route::get('post_request', function()
{  

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $url = "http://bkculv5.local/api_post";

    $response = $client->post($url,[
        'json'=>[
            'judul' => 'title','content' => 'konten'
        ]]);

});
```

and here is my second laravel apps route

```php
Route::post('/api_post', function(Request $request){
    $judul = $request->judul;
    $content = $request->content;

    $artikel = new App\Artikel;
    $artikel->judul = $judul;
    $artikel->content = $content;

    $artikel->save();
});
```

and what I get is

> Server error: `POST http://bkculv5.local/api_post` resulted in a `500
>   Internal Server Error` response:

When I put `myfirstapplaravel.local/api_post` into browser

Any idea why? or do i need to use X-CSRF-TOKEN like when using post in ajax?

#### Update

Here is my error logs in apache xampp

```
[Thu Jul 20 15:26:35.201109 2017] [core:error] [pid 1500:tid 604] (EAI 11002)APR does not understand this error code: AH00549: Failed to resolve server name for 36.86.63.180 (check DNS) -- or specify an explicit ServerName
[Thu Jul 20 15:26:35.439807 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1500:tid 604] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jul 20 15:26:35.487845 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1500:tid 604] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: What error did you get in the log file?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437177/curl-on-local-dev-network-problem-with-virtual-host-naming

Comment: got no idea how to implement it in here...

Comment: Add the appropriate header as in the question, http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your Laravel apps IP inside your Windows host file, also don't forget about CORS. Hope that helps. Also sometimes https can cause issue, but they always have API in their library to skip secure checking (only for development purpose).

```
$client = new Guzzle\Http\Client();
$client->setDefaultOption('verify', '/path/to/cacert.pem');
```

Or, if you need to disable SSL verification:

```
$client->setDefaultOption('verify', false);
```

Comment: yes i already put IP in my hosts file "127.0.0.1    bkculv5.local"

Comment: try CORS and skip https security check. I also have that error when i use guzzle in Laravel.

Comment: i solved the https issue with : https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/394