# php curl error Failed to connect to <host:port>: Connection refused

Tags: php, rest, docker, docker-compose, php-curl

I am getting this error:

> Failed to connect to : Connection refused

when I tried to connect this host in local. But when I tried same endpoint and json data in postman REST client, it worked!

```php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/json'        
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Is `$url` on a `https` domain?

Comment: No. It is http. its on local (vrtualhost)

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437177/curl-on-local-dev-network-problem-with-virtual-host-naming

Comment: I added
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Host: ".$httphost,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

It didnt work

Comment: Do you run your script through a locally-installed PHP or through Docker?

Comment: yes I am using docker

Comment: my code is inside a docker container. Above said API endpoint is also pointing to this container

Comment: I have exposed port 89 to access this container service from other service.So when calling this service, we have to provide http://hostname:89/.   Since this  code is running inside container, there is no point in using this port(89).
We have to use url as http://host:80/. This solved my issue